# What is the difference between rcl and beta5

Tags: debian, apt

I was reading a apt package managing tutorial and came across the acronym RCL.
What does it stand for?  The tutorial says if you download the source from debian unstable and compile and install on debian stable, you get an rcl instead of beta5.
Thank you!

Comment: More context would be essential. Maybe you could link said tutorial?

Comment: Sorry, I can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

RCL stands for [Rogue Class Linux](http://rogueclass.org/).

Comment: But it doesn't look to fit the context.